# Message: Trying to get property 'Cls_Class' of non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

A PHP Error was encountered

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property 'Cls_Class' of non-object
>
> Filename: admin/edit_class.php
>
> Line Number: 42

**Controller :  Classes**

```
public function edit($id)
{

  $data=array();
  $data['Cls_Classid']=$id;
  $this->load->view("admin/admin_header");
  $this->load->view("admin/admin_sidebar");
  $data['t_classes']=$this->ClassesModel->getClass($id);

    $this->load->view("admin/edit_class",$data);
    $this->load->view("admin/admin_footer");
}
```

**Model : ClassesModel**

```
public function getClass($id)
    {
        $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM t_classes INNER JOIN t_teachers ON t_classes.Cls_Teacherid=t_teachers.Tch_Teacherid and t_classes.Cls_Classid = $id ;");
        $query = $this->db->get('t_classes');
        return $query->result();

    }
```

**View :  edit_class**

```
<input type="number" name="c_name"  class="form-control" value="<?php echo $t_classes->Cls_Class;?>">
```

Comment: `Cls_Class` is a field of your database?

Comment: yes it is field

Comment: What is the result of `var_dump($t_classes)` ?